# Prometheus target data export to zabbix

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, zabbix

I would like to access the data that prometheus has fetched from its targets and use this data within zabbix. I am aware of Prometheus Node exporter, which exports the metrics of prometheus itself and not the targets.

Main idea is zabbix would store only the selected data from prometheus in the long-term, while prometheus itself continues to monitor its 100's of targets. Is there an existing solution or some sort of clever path for this problem? (I have though about exporting the requested data to a storage of some sort and fetching this from zabbix, however I would like to 'enable the access' from zabbix and only make changes from zabbix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus supports a REST API of some sort, where it enables you to view the data shown in its GUI. To view all the targets prometheus is monitoring, a simple GET request on

> https://<prometheus host>:9090/api/v1/targets

Returns a JSON containing simple data on the targets.

Further more you are able to create queries to get specific metrics

> https://<prometheus host>:9090/api/v1/query?query=<metric name>

Which returns the exact data including values on the given metric found in targets.

Within Zabbix all that is needed is to make a HTTP agent item containing these specific GET requests (also able to use autodiscovery with this) and configure triggers and such depending on your required usage.

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix can read Prometheus data since 4.2, see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/prometheus

Comment: As mentioned, I am not trying to monitor prometheus itself but get access to the targets prometheus is monitoring. However I managed to find an easy solution to this.